Should expressions like "他妈的" and "狗日的" be modified to "他妈地" and "狗日地" when used to modify verbs and adjectives?
I guess the situation here is like "fucking" and "fuckingly" in English.

No. Here 的 is a sentence-ending particle; placed at the end of a sentence to express affirmation or strengthening the tone.
地 can replace 的 only when 的 is a structural particle placed after an adverbal, such as "慢慢的/地走" (walk slowly) and "高高的/地飛" (fly high).
